# How to know who clicked the Facebook "Like" button on my site?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Can I know who clicked "Like" on my website ?

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: If You consider working with the facebook API programming - then Yes. I agree that it is not pure programming quesion.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Although some FB social plugins show people who have liked your site (e.g. Likebox), actually this is not possible. You can only know how many they are, but not who they are.

Answer (score 6):

You can check all of your facebook friend's wall to see your post. Rather, you could try the following

```
Copy your post link from the address bar.
Go to http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/
Paste your link in "URL to like" text box.
Click preview.
You will see the name + photo of your facebook friend in the right side (Yes, you can see only 2 to 3 friends).
If a person liked your post and not your facebook friend, you can't find him :(
```

Answer (score 5):

Using the API, see this example:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
    function(response) {
        alert('You liked the URL: ' + response);
    }
);
```

I was actually looking for this answer but found it on that page (I almost believed this thread that it wasn't something you can do)

Comment: This isn't telling us anything about who clicked Like button.

Comment: No, this example doesn't, but it shows _how_ you can. I'm assuming you already have a setup to track logged in users or are using the FB API for FB log ins. If you know who the person is, instead of the `alert`, you can make an AJAX call to update a database with the information or do whatever you want. But I didn't dive into the details as the question was vague. Thanks for the downvote...

Answer (score 2):

Can you not view your page on facebook with all the users that 'Like' it?

Answer (score 2):

You can't know who liked it, but you can know count

http://Graph.facebook.com/?id=http://stackoverflow.com

change http://stackoverflow.com with liked site