# How can I get user's facebook ID who clicked like button?

Tags: php, facebook, button, facebook-like

Is there a way to get the user's facebook ID who has clicked like button of the social plugin on my own website?
I couldn't find any way to make it even though I spent for searching it whole day...

Comment: Hopefully you can't. Why should you be automatically notified _who_ has done _what_ through Facebook? It's none of your business.

Comment: You can't and such a question was already answered -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173291/how-to-know-who-clicked-the-facebook-like-button-on-my-site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know it's impossible for you to know who clicked a 'like' button, however if a user logs in to facebook through your site (meaning that you wrote some facebook app which retrieves the info) than you can access the information.

try reading the documentation in api.facebook.com, good luck.