# knowing who has clicked facebook "like" button on your site

Tags: facebook, drupal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to know who clicked the Facebook “Like” button on my site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173291/how-to-know-who-clicked-the-facebook-like-button-on-my-site)

hi , I have included facebook "like" API on one of my blog posts on my website here : http://smtabatabaie.com/Photoshop-works 
and it shows the name of two people who likes this and two others . I want to know the name of the other two people , is there a way ? 
I should mention that my site is built with drupal and it automatically include the facebook like API at the end of every post by using the "facebook like" module 
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It's not an "*API*" it's a [plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/).
2. And for you original question, **No** you can't!