# Get FB User when authenticating to Facebook via Send Button

Tags: facebook

I've done quite a search on SO and this doesn't seem possible.  But I'll ask the question, just in-case someone does know if this is possible.

With the standard like/send buttons.  If an unauthenticated FB user clicks send and via the FB dialog window then authenticates.  Is there a way of finding out the FB id of this user?

Edit: To clarify, this question is not about clicking the like button.  I know you can't get any information from clicking it.  This is about clicking the send button and then post auth with FB.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, as already seen in

- [How to know who clicked the Facebook "Like" button on my site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173291/how-to-know-who-clicked-the-facebook-like-button-on-my-site)
- [How can I get user's facebook ID who clicked like button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418901/how-can-i-get-users-facebook-id-who-clicked-like-button)

You can only track users that allowed an app made by you to access their information.

Comment: I saw those and I asked my question based on the clicking of the "send" button and then authenticating.  I am hoping that upon authentication there is maybe a callback to my site?  This question is not about the like button.

Comment: Facebook made it so that you can only track users who specifically allowed an app made by you, to ensure at least some privacy.